# Is there any way for me to change scoring based on term position in Lucene?

Tags: search, lucene, lucene.net

for example, if I am searching an index of book titles with the term "harry", "Dirty Harry" is scored equally to "Harry Potter", and when two items are equally scored, the order is random.  I'd like to weight the one that begins with my search term (Harry Potter) higher.

I would rather not use TermPostionVector as it seems that this is something I can read only after the search and scoring has been completed.

thanks for your time/consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [spanquery](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/).

Comment: Well, SpanQueries are used only if there're multiple search terms in a query, aren't they? But what if we wish to score `Harry` on the first place always higher than `Harry` on the second, regardless of other search terms, whether they're given in the query or not? Likely in this case we still need to use Spans and something like SpanScorer, but is there any "ready to use" or "recommended" solutions or I should implement it myself?